# Iteration in Xmldocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

```
<Root>
<person name="Tom">
  <Car name="car1" />
  <Car name="car2" />
</Person>
<Person name="Sally">
 <Car name="car3" />
  <Car name="car4" />
</person>
</Root>
```

I am using SelectNodes() method to traverse. However I am having trouble itterating 2 levels down to get the names of all the cars.

```
 var people = Xmldoc.SelectNodes("/Root/Person");
 foreach (XmlNode person in people )
 {
   var cars = person.SelectNodes("/Car");
   foreach(XmlNode car in cars)
    {
      //get the name of the car
    }
 }
```

The statement `person.SelectNodes("/Car")` does not return any results.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the / from your xpath when selecting Car

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   var people = Xmldoc.SelectNodes("/Root/Person");  
foreach (XmlNode person in people )  
{    var cars = person.ChildNodes;    
   foreach(XmlNode car in cars)     
   {       //get the name of the car     }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `.` (dot) in your second xpath,
 i.e. change your line to this:

```
person.SelectNodes("./Car");
```

The *dot* means that you want to query the current node (i.e. person node). Without it, you're querying the whole document.